# Setting global JsonEncoder in Python

Tags: python

Basically, I'm fighting with the age-old problem that Python's default json encoder does not support `datetime`. However all the solutions I can find call to json.dumps and manually pass the "proper" encoder on each invocation. And honestly, that can't be the best way to do it. Especially if you want to use a wrapper like `jsonify` to set up your response object properly, where you can't even specify these parameters.

So: long story short: how to override the global default encoder in Python's JSON implementation to a custom one, that actually does support the features I want?

EDIT: ok so I figured out how to do this for my specific use case (inside Flask). You can do `app.json_encoder = MyCustomJSONEncoder` there. However how to do this outside of flask would still be an interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I could not find a way to set default encoders or decoders for the json module.

So the best way is to do what flask do, that is wrapping the calls to `dump` or `dumps`, and provide a default in that wrapper.

Comment: I've dug into the json module somewhat and you could override the internal _defaultEncoder (or how it's called, not at my work PC now), but that's hugely cringeworthy.

Comment: @FrankyBoy: I avoid as much as I can to use undocumented features because they could change without notice in a future Python version. Sometimes I have to, but then I try to document it in my code as heavily as I can...

Comment: exactly the notion made me throw up in my mouth. That's why I was looking for a proper solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember where I got this solution from but I was searching for it again today and stumbled upon this unanswered question. This works for me:

```py
import json
from datetime import datetime
from uuid import UUID

from pydantic import BaseModel


def setup_custom_json_encoder():
    JSONEncoder_olddefault = json.JSONEncoder.default

    def JSONEncoder_newdefault(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, UUID):
            # if the obj is uuid, we simply return the value of uuid
            return str(obj)
        if isinstance(obj, BaseModel):
            return obj.dict()
        if isinstance(obj, datetime):
            return datetime.isoformat(obj)
        return JSONEncoder_olddefault(self, obj)

    json.JSONEncoder.default = JSONEncoder_newdefault
```

However, this feels "hacky" which is why I was trying to revisit the SO thread I found this in to see if anyone updated it with a cleaner solution